# combine 2 numeric cells in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How to combine 2 columns using DAX.

Expected Format
`71,937,178 (8.09%)`

```
G/L Weekly Revenue and Its PCT = ROUND( 'Calculations'[Weekly Sales], 2 ) & " ( " &  
                                     [Revenue | G/L PCT] & " )"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
G/L Weekly Revenue and Its PCT = ROUND( 'Calculations'[Weekly Sales], 0 ) & " ( " &  
                                     FORMAT([Revenue | G/L PCT], "0.00%") & " )"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FORMAT([Revenue | G/L PCT], "0.00%")
```